# I am new to C++ and I am trying to average a set number of grades given by the user. Stuck with a compiler errors that I can't find

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream.h>

void main()
{
double average;
int GradestoAvg;
int sum = 0;

{
cout << "This program averages grades that the user provides. " << endl;
cout << "How many grades do you want to average?" << endl;
cin >> GradestoAvg;

cout << "Enter Grades:" << endl;
cin << sum;
}


while (GradestoAvg > 0)
average = sum / GradestoAvg;
cout << "The average of the grades is << average <<" endl;
```

Why am I getting a compiler error near the top? It tells me it is expecting a ; near the top where my double average and int GradestoAvg are located. Any thoughts?

Comment: You are missing a closing `}` for the `main()` function.

Comment: The main problem is that you're writing a dialect of C++ that's been obsolete for nearly twenty years. I suggest throwing away whichever book you're learning from and getting a [modern one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242).

Comment: for future occasions, try putting out the error, you are having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thing, you have some mistakes with the cin couts there...
i think something like this would be better

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double average;
  int GradestoAvg;
  int sum = 0;
  int tmp;
  cout << "This program averages grades that the user provides. " << endl;
  cout << "How many grades do you want to average?" << endl;
  cin >> GradestoAvg;
  while (GradestoAvg > 0)
  {
    cout << "Enter Grades:" << endl;
    cin >> tmp;
    sum+= tmp;
    GradestoAvg--;
  }

  average = sum / GradestoAvg;
  cout << "The average of the grades is" << average << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: not angry, it was just that if he was doing some work or practice, you are the finished

Comment: Thanks for your help David. I was just having trouble with the compiling of this program seeing as how this is an assignment I just needed to see what was going on there. The C++ compiler we are using might not allow for certain things but I'll check it out.

Comment: no problem David, @user3416645 if the this answer helped fix his mistake, or fix the error Consider upvote or acept, thank you, could also read this: -> http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

The correct include is `<iostream>` and you need to qualify `cout` and other `std`-scoped variables with `std::` (`std::cout`, `std::endl`).

Also note the potential infinite loop (the `while`), as the condition doesn't appear to change.

Comment: Also the OP needs to sum up the values given from `std::cin`.

Comment: Thanks Luchian I wasn't entirely finished with the code. I just wanted to do a test run first to see if everything was intact I'll be getting there though.

Answer (score 0):

other than as mentioned in other answer, check this line :

```
cin << sum;
```

is `cin >> sum;`